# Django website not responding from VPS on external IP

Tags: django, server, hosting, gunicorn, vps

I am trying to use a VPS from google cloud to host my website. I have installed django, pip3, nginx, gunicorn. When I created a new django project, just to be sure, I tried running it once on the development server. But the VPS is not responding to browser requests. I tried diagnosing the problem and here is all what I found:

1. To check firewall, I ran 'sudo ufw status' and it shows 'status:inactive'
2. To check proxy, I ran 'env | grep proxy' and it returned nothing.
3. To check available IPs, I tried 'sudo netstat -tlnp' and it gives this data:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9278/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      982/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1865/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9278/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1865/sshd
```

I also allowed use of ports using 'sudo ufw allow 8000/tcp'

and here is the ifconfig data:

```
ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.182.0.3  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::4001:aff:feb6:3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 42:01:0a:b6:00:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17772  bytes 134810759 (134.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13098  bytes 1763533 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 462  bytes 50986 (50.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 462  bytes 50986 (50.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

External IP with port in the browser is not responding after writing
`python manage.py runserver`
while the django server is started successfully.
Also, I have included my external IP in the allowed hosts section of settings.py file.